# Sound Synthesis in Clojure, Overtone, Supercollider

Tags: clojure, supercollider

I have just finished
https://github.com/overtone/overtone/wiki/Getting-Started
which is fantastic.

Now, I would like to do more.

I'm a Math/CS Major, so I know what a fourier transform is; however, I have no music background. I would like to learn things like:

- simulating basic percussion instruments
- composing some short pieces.

However, I'm *less* interested in developing those skills from scratch, and *more* interested in having a nice tutorial/guided tour via clojure/overtone/supercollider.

[I find it faster to learn via tweaking something nice; rather than building from scratch for my first runs.]

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any guided tour per se, but Overtone's [examples](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/tree/master/src/overtone/examples) contain a wealth of code for synthesizing various instruments as well as composing pieces from those instruments and/or sampled instruments.  I personally recommend [`bells.clj`](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/blob/master/src/overtone/examples/compositions/bells.clj) (synthesized bells + composition) and [`auto_dubstep.clj`](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/blob/master/src/overtone/examples/compositions/auto_dubstep.clj) (synthesized drums + composition)

Comment: Started playing with the examples last night. Pretty impressive. However a little more docs + the math behind why stuff works would be a little nice. Sound processing = black magic to me right now.

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't exactly answer your question (not clojure related), but i am pretty sure you will appreciate dave benson's [mathematics and music](http://www.scribd.com/doc/35803084/Mathematics-and-Music-Dave-Benson) (seems he also has other books, but that is free online).

Comment: That book was meanwhile removed by Scribd's copyright protection system. Was it [this one](https://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/mth192/pages/html/music.pdf) ?

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of example on making sounds, though when getting started with Overtone (I am still 99% newb) It took too long to discover the `line` function which prevents you from leaking synth descriptors and `metronome` which is for causing sounds to happen at times.

```
(definst
    ... create component sounds ...
    (out 0 (* v (clip2 (+ wob (* kick-vol kick) (* snare-vol snare)) 1)
              (line:kr 0 dur dur FREE)))
```

multiplying by a call to `line:kr` create a synth with a defined lifetime

then you can use a `metronome` for composition as in this little beat:

```
(defn beat2 [beat]
  (at (metro beat) (#'kick 220 0.3 0.5 1.5))
  (at (+ 0.5  (metro beat)) (#'kick 220 0.3 0.5 1.5))
  (if (= 0 (mod beat 2))
    (at (metro (+ 0.17 beat)) (#'kick)))
  (at (metro (+ 0.35 beat)) (c-hat))
  (if (even? beat) (at (metro (+ 0.45 beat)) (c-hat)))
  (at (metro (+ 0.5 beat)) (#'mew 8))
  (apply-at (metro (inc beat))
            (if (= 0 (mod beat 200)) #'beat1 #'beat2)
            (inc beat) []))
```

Comment: Metronome is important. Thanks!